# PHP - Criar um array associativo do banco

Tags: php, mysql, array-associativo

Eu tenho as informações abaixo num banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quero o resultado em um array assim:

```
['CLARO' => "IPHONE 8", "VIVO" => "MOTO ONE", "TIM" => "ZENFONE 6", "CLARO" => "IPHONE 8", "CLARO" => GALAXY S9", "TIM" => "MOTO ONE Z", "TIM" => "MOTO ONE Z", "VIVO" => "MOTO ONE" e "VIVO" => "GALAXY S10"]
```

Até agora não deu muito certo (kkkkkkk) e estou com o seguinte código:

```php
$t_op  = array();
$t_mod = array();

$t_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT operadora, modelo FROM sdc_tm_aparelhos WHERE id <> 1");
while ($t_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t_result)) {    
    $t_op[]  = $t_row['operadora'];
    $t_mod[] = $t_row['modelo'];
}
foreach ($t_op as $um) {
    foreach ($t_mod as $dois) {
        $novo = array($um=>$dois);
    }
}
print_r($novo);
```

Esse código me apresenta o seguinte na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei solução aqui no site mas não encontrei exatamente o que eu precisa, se alguém souber responder ou indicar algum outro tópico bem próximo a isso que preciso agradeço!

Comment: Mas se tiver 2 com TIM o que ocorre? Não vai funcionar, é associativo, cada key representa somente um, a não ser que cada value seja um sub-array, ou seja um array com mais de uma dimensão.

Comment: A resposta do @AugustoVasques não deu certo ainda, gerou um array multimensional gigante...

Comment: Escrevi errado. Troque os **dois últimos** `foreach` por `array_combine($t_op, $t_mod);`. Mas vai o correr o que o @GuilhermeNascimento comentou é um array associativo e as chaves duplicadas serão sobreescritas.

Comment: E tem alguma outra maneira de fazer isso sem sobrescrever as chaves mesmo que seja por outra forma que não a de array associativo? Já tentei usar o array_combine e até array_merge e array_merge_recursive mas nenhum funcionou...

Comment: Pensei em outra saída, mas não sei como fazer, pegar o ID da tabela também e usar como chave, porque daí ficaria única. A questão é se dá pra fazer array associativo com 3 elementos (acho que só dá multidimensional, né?) ou cair de volta na questão do array multidimensional mas daí não precisaria pegar o ID...

Comment: O que dá para fazer é uma array cujo as chaves são os nomes das operadoras e cada valor é um array contendo os modelos.

Comment: Mas por que existem modelos iguais para a mesma operadora? Por exemplo, tem "moto one z" duas vezes em "tim". É preciso mesmo duplicar o modelo na array?

Comment: Sim porque na tabela cada aparelho possui um IMEI diferente e também cada operadora pode fornecer uma infinidade de aparelhos. Estou tentando montar um array multi mas to apanhando...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como criar array associativo com valores de chaves duplicadas, elas são únicas.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma array associativo multidimensional onde os valores das chaves ficariam nessa estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que a estrutura é uma array da operadora com os modelos, e nos modelos outra array com os id's (que você pode substituir por outro dado do banco).

O código ficaria assim:

```
$novo  = array();

$t_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, operadora, modelo FROM sdc_tm_aparelhos WHERE id <> 1");
while ($t_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t_result)) {
   $novo[$t_row['item']][$t_row['nivel']][] = $t_row['id'];
}

print_r($novo);
```